# Knockout/Underscore - data-bind on first div

Tags: knockout.js, data-binding, underscore.js, visible

```
<script type="text/html" id="RevealPanelStart">
    <div class="alert alert-danger" data-bind="visible:$root.addToBasketPreviewDisplayed">Before you add to basket, please check you are happy with the options selected below:</div>
    <div class="revealpanel" data-bind="visible:$root.previewClicked, template: { name:$root.templateToUse, foreach:Fields }" style="display: none;">
    </div>
</script>
```

This can appear multiple times throughout the code. Is there anyway I can show the first addToBasketPreviewDisplayed?

I've tired:

```
_.first(model.addToBasketPreviewDisplayed(true));
model.addToBasketPreviewDisplayed(true).first;
```

Thanks,

Clare

Answer (score 0):

There is only one `addToBasketPreviewDisplayed`. You're indicating it is a member of your (root) viewmodel. It doesn't matter how many times it appears in the HTML, it's all referencing the same thing, unless this is part of a component, in which case, you want to find the first component. The bottom line is that you should be looking at your viewmodel for how your data is structured. The view is just how the viewmodel is presented.

Comment: The code above is located within the js file. I was thinking something like this: if (model.isValid()) 
{
 // Only change this to true on the first div
 model.addToBasketPreviewDisplayed(true);
} but I don't know what to put inside, unless I jump out of Knockout and do it in js using $(...).First().Show()?

Comment: Can you make a very small fiddle that demonstrates your problem? I think the problem is in your viewmodel design. `addToBasketPreviewDisplayed` should not be part of the root viewmodel.